# TFIDF with previously preprocessed data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to use several information retrieval techniques one after another. For each one i want the texts to be preprocessed in exactly the same way. My preprocessed texts are provided as a list of lists of words. Unfortunately scikit-learns TfidfVectorizer seems to only accept lists of strings. Currently i am doing it like this (which is of course very inefficient):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

train_data = [["the","sun","is","bright"],["blue","is","the","sky"]]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda i:i.split(","))
converted_train = map(lambda i:",".join(i), train_data)
result_train = tfidf.fit_transform(converted_train)
```

Is there a way to use scikit-learns TfidfVectorizer to perform information retrieval directly on this kind of preprocessed data?

If not, is it instead possible to let the TfidfVectorizer do the preprocessing and to reuse its preprocessed data afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself. My problem was, that I simply used None as the tokenizer of the TfidfVectorizer:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=None)
```

You have to instead use a tokenizer which just forwards the data. Also you have to make sure, the vectorizer does not convert the lists to lower case (which doesn't work). A working example is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

train_data = [["the","sun","is","bright"],["blue","is","the","sky"]]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda i:i, lowercase=False)
result_train = tfidf.fit_transform(train_data)
```